# Resharper skip migrations from being analyzed

Tags: c#, resharper

I've got a decent sized project with a lot of migrations over time.
Sometimes it takes a huge amount of time to refactor because resharper is analyzing all migrations - is there a way to exclude specific folders?

[image]

I have tried to exclude the folders in resharper but that doesnt seem to work for refactorings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to place the ignore pattern under *ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Generated Code*:
[image]

Comment: I've removed the migrations from my exclude and i've added this. I'll check and see if this improves the speed of resharper now and then ill accept your answer if all checks out :)

Comment: Fingers crossed 